# NSBox and Auto Layout

Tags: macos, cocoa

Trying to use a `NSBox` to get a background color which works with dark mode, it behaves differently than a `NSView`.

The `NSBox` is created in Interface Builder, and doesn't work with Auto Layout. It is not resizing any child views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using *Interface Builder > Editor > Embed In > Box*, there is a bug. The NSBox `autoresizesSubviews` property is set to **NO**, instead of **YES**.

[image]

> When the value of this property is YES and the view’s frame changes, the view automatically calls the resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: method to facilitate the resizing of its subviews. When the value of this property is NO, the view does not autoresize its subviews.
>   **The default value of this property is YES**.

rdar://47701604

[image: Autoresizes subviews]